# ImageResizer license and plugin questions

Tags: asp.net, imageresizer

1. I am targeting the free edition (http://imageresizing.net/plugins/editions/free). I dont see any issues for using this in a commercial production environment but is it ok to use for paid apps?
2. Theres a lot of advice on using the disk cache plugin, although the site would be heavily used is this plugin really necessary as the most the plugin would be doing is to show thumbnails, resize images where necessary and upload images to in order to resize them appropriately.
3. It will be used in an ASP .Net project (not MVC). Could i continue to install by using the commands (correct me if im wrong but i dont think this installs ImageResizer to carry out what i need it to?)

   PM> Install-Package ImageResizer.MvcWebConfig

   PM> Install-Package ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache

   PM> Install-Package ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs

Or is there an alternative Package Manager install option for an ASP .Net site? At present Im downloading the entire package but ideally i hate to install everything only to get one component if thats all that i require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are no problems whatsoever using the Essential Edition plugins in a paid or commercial app. In V4, we will be dual-licensing Essential Edition under the Apache license to make this clearer.
2. Yes, permanent caching of some kind is an absolute must, or you won't scale past a few concurrent visitors. You have many options; DiskCache (paid), TinyCache (free, essential), or any kind of CDN or reverse proxy (higher latency, more cache misses than DiskCache).
3. The ImageResizer.Mvc package is required for any type of ASP.NET project using .NET 4.0 or higher.